# Record deletion when a field updates with time delay

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have a field type checkbox and I want a related record to be deleted when this check box is checked, however the deletion should happen 6 months after the checkbox is updated, how to do that?
In process builder I thought an apex could be called, but I can't set the date for the scheduling 6 months after, it doesn't show this custom checkbox as a date source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criteria for the Process Builder would be "when checkbox is true". The scheduled time would be "182 days from now." You'll still need to build a flow or write Apex code to delete the records, since Process Builder cannot delete records.